# angular2 Routing issue with pathmatch

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

So I decided to retry the angular2 tutorial, since last time I had some issues with the router (sound familiar?). See link:
[Angular 2 tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html)
Where I followed every step, got everything to work, until I got to the redirect section.

```
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/dashboard',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

Where it hangs on the "pathMatch". Even when I try to restart with "npm start" in the command window, I get this error:

```
app/app.routes.ts(11,5): error TS2322: Type '({ path: string; redirectTo: string; pathMatch: string; } | { path: string; component: typeof Das...' is not assignable to type 'Route[]'.
```

My router version defined in package.json is:
    "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7", of which i thought was the latest version?

How can I check which routerversion is actually installed on my project/pc? I'm kind of new to the whole npm-deal and I'm getting stumped trying to figure this thing out. I'm guessing I may have an old router version?

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Please, provide more code about how you are importing and defining your component.

Comment: @angular/router: 3.0.0-beta.1 is the latest version of the angular 2 router module. Here are links to my router-related configurations for the tutorial:
https://github.com/JaimeStill/Angular2---TourOfHeroes/blob/master/TourOfHeroes.Web/package.json
https://github.com/JaimeStill/Angular2---TourOfHeroes/blob/master/TourOfHeroes.Web/app/main.ts
https://github.com/JaimeStill/Angular2---TourOfHeroes/blob/master/TourOfHeroes.Web/app/app.routes.ts

Comment: @JaimeStill it's actually `3.0.0-beta.2`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, thanks, I was going off of the module used in the tutorials on the angular.io site.

Comment: @JaimeStill & GüntherZöchbauer, thanks. 
I used the 3.0.0-beta.2 in my package.json, but now i get unmet dependency errors when i do npm install.  Tried the quickstart package.json file, which has a 3.0.0-beta.1 but to no avail. Should i just start over?

Comment: Did you re-run npm install (or restore packages if using Visual Studio 2015)? Which version of Angular 2 are you using?

Comment: @GüntherZöchbauer & JaimeStill after a few other tries and a typings install i managed to get it working. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: @JaimeStil, yes did multiple npm installs with a copy of the package.json on this page: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html
finally it did a typings install and after that i could start it fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I guess you should have found the answer by now, but here is how you can check which version of router is installed on your system

Go into node_modules folder and then into @angular, and into router

node_modules/@angular/router
├── README.md
├── bundles
├── index.d.ts
├── index.js
├── index.js.map
├── index.metadata.js`enter code here`on
├── package.json   <----------- This file should tell you the Version
├── src

I hope your problem was solved.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for providing that answer!